# Get lightning:inputField value in javascript controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have following code in component which is called by another lightning component from aura:iteration. I want to get value from lightning inputField when it is changed in the javascript controller and store in v.item.Rep_Name1__c. BTW Rep_Name1__c is a lookup field.How can we achieve it?

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="OPS__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'OPS__c' } "/>
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" 
                            recordTypeId="0121N000001TLGbQAO"
                            objectApiName="OPS__c">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Rep_Name1__c" value="{!v.item.Rep_Name1__c}" aura:id="testpp" onchange="{!c.getOppProcess}"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Javascript Controller (I am getting undefined when I try to retrieve value)

```
({
getOppProcess: function(component, event, helper) {
    debugger;
    var test = component.find("testpp").get("v.value");
},
)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far in order to achieve this? have you encoutnered any problems while doing so? if so, please include any errors verbatim.

Comment: i have updated my question. I am getting undefined when I try to retrieve inputfield value on change.

Comment: Is that a typo in your JS? You seem to find **testpp** whereas the id defined is  **testp**

Comment: typo mistake while writing question :)
PS Edited question

Comment: You need to use "aura:id" instead of "id" in the inputfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. 
I was retrieving the value in a wrong way.
The correct code is

```
getOppProcess: function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("v.item.Rep_Name1__c", event.getParam('value'));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using **id** attribute here:

```
<lightning:inputField id="testpp" fieldName="Rep_Name1__c" value="{!v.item.Rep_Name1__c}" onchange="{!c.getOppProcess}"/>
```

Whereas, you need to use **aura:id** here to be able to get the value in your JS:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="testpp" fieldName="Rep_Name1__c" value="{!v.item.Rep_Name1__c}" onchange="{!c.getOppProcess}"/>
```

Comment: it was just typo mistake while writing question. But i am not getting any value even if i use aura:id

Comment: I was able to get this running and was able to fetch the value in my JS with similar implementation. You may like to view if you are missing something in your code, because the one you posted here had typos, so something to look at.